# How do I get the minimum value between 25 hours ago in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In my strategy, I want to set the stoploss as the minimum price between 24 hours.

---

```
lowest = ta.lowest(low, 25)

if (4.2 >= stoploss and stoploss >= 1.7)
    strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, when=long)
    strategy.exit("exit", "LONG", loss= lowest, profit= close * 4)
```

---

However, if I use the lowest I set,
the bar will continue to pile up after entering from the long,
and the minimum value will change.

How can I use it as a stoploss by fixing the minimum value between 25 hours?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `var` if you want to save some data.

> var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the
> variable.

So, as long as you don't assign a new value to it, it will keep its value.

So, something like this:

```
var float lowest_at_entry = na
lowest = ta.lowest(low, 25)

if (long)  // Your long condition
    lowest_at_entry := lowest
```